# "Operator '+=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'" error even though I am only using Vector2

Tags: unity-game-engine

I searched up the problem with this error and it it apparently a problem with adding a Vector3/Vector2 to a Vector2/Vector3 (makes sense), but I did not use Vector3 here at all. What is the problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquareScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector2(0, 1 / 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a Vector3 with Z set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do.

```
transform.position += new Vector2(0, 1 / 100);
```

is the same as

```
transform.position = transform.position + new Vector2(0, 1 / 100);
```

so you're adding `transform.position` (which is a `Vector3`) to the new `Vector2`.

Comment: The other way round, you add a `Vector2` to the `Vector3` .. still that doesn't provide an answer for what to do instead though ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) is always a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html).

You are adding a `Vector2`.

For both there exists a `+` operator .. but not for the mixed types.

Additionally since there is [implicit conversions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html) forth [and back](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector3.html) between `Vector3` and `Vector2` - which btw is the reason why

```
transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

works - the compiler doesn't know whether it rather shall convert the `transform.position` to `Vector2` and then perform a [`Vector2 + Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_add.html) operation, or whether rather convert your new `Vector2` to a `Vector3` and then perform a [`Vector3 + Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html) operation.

That's why it says it is ambiguous.

You could of course explicitly force one conversion and do

```
transform.position += (Vector3) new Vector2(0, 1 / 100);
```

---

Since you only want the Y part anyway you could simply use

```
transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1 / 100); // equals new Vector3 (0, 1/100, 0)
```

or also

```
transform.position += Vector3.up * 1 / 100;
```

---

**BUT**

```
1/100
```

is also an integer division! And results in `0`! You probably wanted `1f / 100f` to have a float division

---

And finally this still would be frame rate dependent and you rather want to use [`* Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to convert into a frame rate independent value per second.